# Console Screen Hides after implementing a API function from (windows.h)in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console, header-files

I am new to C language but having experience in higher level language such as java, python.....etc.

I am trying to resize the console window in Windows OS. Using the "SetConsoleWindowInfo and SetConsoleScreenBufferSize" function from "windows.h" header file.

But while I try to run that code the console window hides in the taskbar and nothing is happening. While I try to run the code in vsCode the integrated terminal prints nothing.

Here is my code

```
void setConsole(short consolePos_X, short consolePos_Y, short consoleWidth, short consoleHeight){

HANDLE wConsoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

SMALL_RECT consoleWinSize = {consolePos_X, consolePos_Y, consolePos_X+consoleWidth, consolePos_Y+consoleHeight};
SetConsoleWindowInfo(wConsoleHandle, TRUE, &consoleWinSize);

COORD buffSize = {100, 50};
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(wConsoleHandle, buffSize);
SetConsoleTitle("Snake Game");
```

I think the problem is with setting buffersize but I am not sure.

Hope I will get Solution.
Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: Test for errors (including `GetLastError`).  Say what values you pass in to `setConsole`.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: Please use only one of the tag **C** or **C++**. They are different languages. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68192633/edit) your message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I Found The Solution.

The problem is that the "ConsoleScreenBufferSize" should not be less than the "ConsoleWindowSize" ([More info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/window-and-screen-buffer-size)). But I have used a "BufferSize" which is less than the "ConsoleSize". So the problem aries.

Solution for this problem is just to use the "BufferSize" Greater than or equal to the "ConsoleSize".
As follows:

```
 COORD coord = {consoleWidth, consoleHeight};
     SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &coord);
```

And this just works fine.
If you have anydoubts fell free to comment here.
I will try to answer in my free time

Hope this is useful..!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follow:

```
HANDLE wConsoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
if (wConsoleHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    fprintf(stderr, "GetStdHandle failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}
```

There should be no error here, unless your application has no console allocated.

And also change as follow:

```
if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(wConsoleHandle, TRUE, &consoleWinSize)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SetConsoleWindowInfo failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}
```

It is likely that the error is 87 (Invalid parameter). Check the values, especially the consoleWinSize. If it is, then look at [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=SetConsoleWindowInfo+fails+with+error+87) and [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/dosbox/code-0/HEAD/tree/dosbox/trunk/src/debug/debug_win32.cpp).